# Do Recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener support remote control input?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As per my question, I am wondering if the `RecyclerView` can respond to a remote control's Enter button just like a normal touch event.

This is currently my code.

```
lstAmbiance.addOnItemTouchListener(new AmbianceAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), lstAmbiance, new AmbianceAdapter.ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        //some code

    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s create an inner class implementing RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

```
class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

private ClickListener clicklistener;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recycleView, final ClickListener clicklistener){

    this.clicklistener=clicklistener;
    gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child=recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
            if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null){
                clicklistener.onLongClick(child,recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
    if(child!=null && clicklistener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
        clicklistener.onClick(child,rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
}
```

let’s add the ItemTouchListener to the RecyclerView, where we will pass RecyclerTouchListener class. This will implement onClick and onLongClick methods. These methods will listen for the click and long press events on the particular position of the view.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
    recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
    //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on position        :"+position,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position :"+position,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}));

Accessing a Particular View Component in the RecyclerView Item

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
    recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
    //Values are passing to activity & to fragment as well
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on position :"+position,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ImageView picture=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Single Click on Image :"+position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position :"+position,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}));

Comment: could you explain this a bit more in detail.

Comment: So, in short, it really does support remote control Enter input?